# Insertion through sqlalchemy to_sql procedure on AWS ec2 instance; facing issue with a column of bit data type

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, sqlalchemy

I am trying to copy the data from mysql to postgresql using python. I didn't had any problem with redhat linux instance for this task, when I use exact same code on my new AWS EC2 instance I am facing an error in one table for a particular column of bit datatype in mysql.

It is throwing me an error "A string literal cannot contain NUL (0x00) characters."

- I tried encoding from latin to utf8 as our databases are different Mysql is latin and Postgresql is utf8.
- I tried using astype function to change at dataframe level but no luck.
- I tried changing the datatype from text to bytea.

After looking at many places I decided to take your help in solving this error. Please note that the same piece of code is working on Redhat linux with python 2.7 but isn't working on AWS EC2 instance.

My code is very simple.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import MySQLdb

mysql_con = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx-1.rds.amazonaws.com', user = 'xx', passwd = 'xxxxxxxx', db = 'xxxxx', port = xxx)
mysql_cur = mysql_con.cursor()

engine = create_engine('postgresql://xx:xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-1.rds.amazonaws.com:xxxx/xx')


mysql_table = pd.read_sql("""select * from table order by 1 asc limit 10""",mysql_con)

mysql_table.to_sql('dummy_table', engine,if_exists = 'replace',index=False,schema = "XX")
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a NUL character into a PostgreSQL string attribute. And if you managed to get it into the database, you'd end up with data corruption.

You'll have to fix the data in the MySQL database first or filter out the NUL characters in your code before you insert the data into PostgreSQL.

If you got it to work before, that means that either the database you tried had no NUL characters in it, or you did it with a very old version of PostgreSQL that did not check well enough.